# pdo - get number of rows for multiple tables as separate queries?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

I need to get the row count from multiple tables using the same conditions with pdo.  For example, this would give me the row count for table `users`.

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `account_id` = ? AND (`computer_name` = 'name1' OR `computer_name` = 'name2' OR `computer_name` = 'name3');
$stmt->execute(array($_SESSION['user']['account_id']));

$result = $stmt->fetchColumn();
```

Now, I want to run the same query, but with different tables... for instance... `users1`, `users2`, `users3`, `users4`, etc.

The tables are all different of course, but all will have columns `account_id` and `computer_name`.  Is it possible to join all these tables in some way and still get a count for each specifically or will I need to run multiple selects to the database for each one?

The goal is to create a display for the logged in user which shows how many records are in the database for different tables.

Expected result is something where I can get total row counts for each table that meet the WHERE clause conditions :

```
users1 = 50
users2 = 34
users3 = 82
...etc
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this query:

```
SELECT 'users' as tbl, count(*) as cnt FROM `users` 
WHERE `account_id` = ? AND (`computer_name` = 'name1' OR `computer_name` = 'name2' OR `computer_name` = 'name3')
UNION
SELECT 'users2' as tbl, count(*) as cnt FROM `users2` 
WHERE `account_id` = ? AND (`computer_name` = 'name1' OR `computer_name` = 'name2' OR `computer_name` = 'name3')
UNION
SELECT 'users3' as tbl, count(*) as cnt FROM `users3` 
WHERE `account_id` = ? AND (`computer_name` = 'name1' OR `computer_name` = 'name2' OR `computer_name` = 'name3')
```

And then pass the appropriate number of parameters:

```
$stmt->execute(array_fill(0, 3, $_SESSION['user']['account_id']));
```

Comment: This works awesome... is it possible to break down another level on a specific table then?  Like say, on table users2 I added `type` LIKE 'something' in the where clause... since I am using the same table would I still do an entirely new union?

Comment: Yes, in that case you need to add another `UNION` block, even if on the same table. Each count with a different `WHERE` clause requires a new `UNION`.

Comment: Thanks... I assume this would be less resource intensive than separate queries for each as there is only one call right?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, in order to get the count you will have to join all the data tables together on the appropriate foreign keys.

Comment: But can I still get a count for each specific table? Users1 = 50, users2 = 350, etc...